# Passing a struct to a callback that takes a variable of type void*

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to pass a struct to a callback set with curl_easy_setopt. Here's the struct:

```
typedef struct gfcontext_t {
  int sockfd;
  char requested_path[1024];
  char path[1024];
} gfcontext_t;

struct gfcontext_t ctx;
```

I've got these two lines setting up the callback:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ctx);
```

and the callback itself looks like this:

```
size_t write_callback(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
  printf("userp: %s\n", userp.requested_path);
}
```

The machine says "request for member ‘requested_path’ in something not a structure or union." So I guess the struct (ctx) is not being passed correctly. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: the type is `void *`, not `void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

userp is a pointer. You should type cast it to `gfcontext_t *`.

```
printf("userp: %s\n", ((gfcontext_t *)userp)->requested_path);
```

Comment: Of course. I still can never quite get my mind around pointers. Thanks.